# java reactive flow - can a subscriber return value?

Tags: observer-pattern, publisher, subscriber, java-flow

I am trying to implement java reactive flow (observer design patter).

I made use of samples available. i have no problem sending values to the subscribers but i cannot make the subscriber to send the publisher back a value. Is there any way i can make it return a value after lets say process it?

i am happy to hear any other approach also.

i tried this sample https://dzone.com/articles/reactive-streams-in-java-9

i am using it for automated trading. i have a each thread for each stock. each thread sends messages to strategies... once the strategy is success, i want it to send me back the result

Comment: The observer pattern is unidirectional with values. You can only send items to one direction so you need multiple flows if you need to send values back. However, bidirectionality usually complicates things and often is not really necessary as usually there another way, for example, processing the item further down. What do you want to achieve with sending items up?

Comment: i am using it for automated trading. i have a each thread for each stock. each thread sends messages to strategies... once the strategy is success, i want it to send me back the result

Comment: That sounds more like a job for an actor system where you can sand messages back and forth.